# Can Java's HashMap overflow silently?

Tags: java, memory-management, hashmap, overflow

In Java, can a [`java.util.HashMap<Key, Value>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) overflow silently, so content is deleted without me receiving an exception or some other notification? If yes, how do I make it noticeable?

I meant can it exceed the physical hardware memory, not the reserved memory for the `HashMap` object.

Comment: This doesnt make sense. `HashMap`s dynamically grow in size, and have no limit. Every value has a specific key, and unless you remove it yourself, it'll stay there (unless you're using a `WeakHashMap`, in which things will be removed from the map if the only reference to that item is the map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `HashMap`s do not evict elements automatically. If the buckets get too full, the buckets are expanded and all the elements are rehashed automatically.

Comment: I meant can if it exceeds the physical hardware memory, not the reserved memory for the hashmap-object.

Comment: @DBRN Then you will receive an `OutOfMemoryError`, and life will suck for you. But your `HashMap` still won't lose elements. Also, before getting to this point, your GC will be running at 100% continuously trying to free up memory, and your program will be very slow....

Comment: So there is no way an OutOfMemoryError would be not thrown or be invisible?

Comment: An `OutOfMemoryError` will indeed be thrown. In theory, code can catch it, but catching `Error`s of any type is bad practice, so don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> When the number of entries in the hash table exceeds the product of
>   the load factor and the current capacity, the hash table is rehashed
>   (that is, internal data structures are rebuilt) so that the hash table
>   has approximately twice the number of buckets

A `HashMap` will never "overflow", it will simply resize.  This will repeatedly happen until you run out of memory, which will cause a [very loud error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are correct but there is one weird edge-case. See [Theoretical limit for number of keys (objects) that can be stored in a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4123743/823393) and the discussion about what happens when there are more entries in the `Map` than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

As such it would be theoretically possible - if you somehow managed to break that limit (which is close to impossible) **and** the JVM survived handling that many objects (which is close to impossible) **and** your program survived that limit (which is close to impossible) then not only would objects begin to seem to disappear from your `Map` but you would be half way to earning yourself a breakfast at [Milliways](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Milliways) where *If you've done six impossible things this morning, why not round it off with breakfast at Milliways, the Restaurant at the End of the Universe*.