# How do I read a file in Java char by char into an integer array?

Tags: java

I have a file filled with all numbers with no spaces. 
I am trying to read this file in Java character by character into an integer array. 
I tried reading the file as an String then step through it char by char into an array but i think the file exceeded the String size limit.

Comment: well if it exceeds the max String size, it will also exceed the max int array size both Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: Please be more specific. So your file contains "1234567890...." - now what should be in your integer array [1, 2, 3, 4, ... ] or what?

Comment: How many bytes is the length of your file?

Comment: Post some code with the results you get and the results expected, or you will get this question closed since it sounds like a "please do my homework"  question.

Answer (score 1):

As @Scary Wombat suggest, both of the max size of String and max size of array are `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. We can refer to  [String max size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816142/strings-maximum-length-in-java-calling-length-method), [Array max size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size) and [List max size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767979/how-many-data-a-list-can-hold-at-the-maximum). Note, the specific max size should be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - 1 or -2 or -5 is irrelevant with this topic. For insurance purpose, we can use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` - 6.

I suppose your number is very large and the amount of character in the file may exceed the maximum of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` according to

> I tried reading the file as an String then step through it char by
>   char into an array but i think the file exceeded the String size
>   limit.

To handle the maximum, I suggest you create another `List` to hold the integer. The core concept of it is like `dynamic array` but there are some differences. For `dynamic array`, you are applying for another memory space and copy current elements into that space.  You can refer to the code below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{        
            File file = new File("number.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listContainer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int item;
            while((item = reader.read()) != -1){
                /*
                 * I assume you want to get the integer value of the char but not its ascii value
                 */
                list.add(item - 48);
                /*
                 * Reach the maximum of ArrayList and we should create a new ArrayList instance to hold the integer
                 */
                if(list.size() == Integer.MAX_VALUE - 6){
                    listContainer.add(list);
                    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                }
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```