# Is arraylist in java good to use for the no of test cases of 10^9 with maximum no of elements with maximum size possible?

Tags: java

I have used arraylist for the same in a TCS hiring contest for a question in java and my friend use vector in c++ but my I didn't qualify and he did, but both had the same logic..what should I do for the next time .please give suggestion

Comment: A little too less information. Maybe explain a bit what the requirments are. And why your ArrayList approuch wasn't qualified?

Comment: What is the type of the elements stored in the ArrayList?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As @n247s said, please edit your question and include more details about the requirements and what your approach was. Cheers :)

Comment: Please add the code of both the solutions, yours and your friend's.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this snippet to test your scenario -

```
BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.valueOf(10).pow(9);
    ArrayList<BigDecimal> arr = new ArrayList();

    while(i.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0) {
        arr.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
        i.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
    }
```

OUTPUT ->

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>     at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)

On the other hand, **LinkedList** holds up better(Reference:[How much data can a List can hold at the maximum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767979/how-much-data-can-a-list-can-hold-at-the-maximum)) but fails in the end ->

```
BigDecimal i = BigDecimal.valueOf(10).pow(9);
    BigDecimal value = i;
    LinkedList<BigDecimal> ll = new LinkedList<>();

    while(i.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0) {
        ll.add(value);
        i.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
    }
```

OUTPUT ->

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead
>   limit exceeded