# Java: Parsing a CSV file intermittently fails to read 170K lines in File

Tags: java

I have a CSV file containing customer info, one customer each row.

The CSV file has a size of about 170,000 lines.

The app first parsed the whole file line by line and saved each line as a Customer object into an `ArrayList`. It implied that the size of the list would also be in the order of 170k.

The code is like the below:

```
final class CustomerInfoLineProcessor implements LineProcessor<CustomerInfo> {    
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean processLine(final String line) {
        parseLine(line);
        return true;
    }

    private void parseLine(final String line) {
        try {
            if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                  //do job
            }
        } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
            handleLineError(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage(), e, lineStatus);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

It was found intermittently that the parsing process ended abnormally in the middle. No errors or runtime exceptions were thrown. The whole process was also not stopped. The app kept doing further jobs based on whatever inside the `ArrayList`.

In the beginning, I thought there might be some invisible characters hidden somewhere in the file, which caused the process quit early. But the possibility was excluded after the same file was tested without any problem by the same app on my test machine.

The second guess was: the memory setting -Xmx256m was too small, thus I changed it to an even smaller one, -Xmx128m. The app  immediately threw an `OutOfMemoryError`, and the app was terminated automatically. It implied that the memory usage of -Xmx256m seemed not to be an issue.

Any other reasons I have not yet thought about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much data can a List can hold at the maximum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767979/how-much-data-can-a-list-can-hold-at-the-maximum)

Comment: Maybe post the code that stores the customer into the ArrayList, if you think that this is where it's failing?

Comment: Are you tried with BufferedReader? See it example thats read a csv file: http://www.java67.com/2015/08/how-to-load-data-from-csv-file-in-java.html

Comment: @fantaghirocco:  *Definitely* not a dupe.

Comment: So I suppose one piece of information we're missing is how the file itself is opened and read in.  This looks to be the "meat" of the code which handles the parsing, but if you're opening and loading the entire file into memory at once, that might explain why you're getting an `OutOfMemoryError` if your memory is set too low.

Comment: This is an existing app. The file is read in like,                          try (final Reader reader = Files.newReader(customerFile, Charsets.UTF_8)) {
                            customerSync.executeSync(affiliateId, reader);
                        } Here Files is in google's common package, not that in java 8.

Comment: You say intermittently. Does it consistently fail on the same CSV file? If not, it can't be anything about the contents of the file.

Comment: no, sometimes failed, other times not. It confused me.

Comment: I don't like the current handling of the file: parsing each line of the file and saving the result into a list, which made the list's size huge; then syncing the data in the list one by one with the database. In this way, it used a huge chunk of memory.

Comment: need to find a way, like streaming file data and handle it piece by piece. However, we use java 7, not java 8.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the problem found. 
* the client's app ftp the csv file to us in a specified folder every morning;
* then the file_sync app started parsing the cvs file;
* sometimes the cvs file's ftp transferring was not complete while the file_sync app was kicked started. It caused the problem.

Thus the solution is to make sure the csv file is not being opened by another process before starting the file_sync app.