# JPA repository findAll() limit

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi I just wanted to know is there any limit for retrieving row from MYSQL database using JPARepository.findAll() , I have around 3700000 entries in my database. If I use findAll() do I get all the entries or truncated count?

Comment: When in doubt, check the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findAll--). It says - `all entities`.

Answer (score 1):

You will receive *all* entities until something breaks.

Things that might break:

- List implementations may have a size constraint. See [How much data can a List can hold at the maximum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767979/how-much-data-can-a-list-can-hold-at-the-maximum)
- The memory of your computer is limited.
- The size of your JVM heap is limited.
- The duration your user is willing to wait for a result is limited.

As a rule of thumb: Never plan to have millions of JPA entities in memory.
Either process them in batches using pagination as [*Jimmy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73612529/66686) proposed.
Or use some other technology that scales better, e.g. [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) and one of it's `query` methods taking a [`RowCallbackHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not use findAll if there are a lot of entities. You can use pagination something like, ( taking no of records in single page as ***SIZE***):

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, SIZE);  // for example SIZE = 500
Page<Qmail> page = repository.findAll(pageable);

while (!page.isEmpty()) {
    pageable = pageable.next();

    //   TODO WITH ENTITIES    
    page.forEach( entity -> SOP(entity.getId()) );

    page = repository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

Comment: I need all entries for a caching purpose